# "Does not make sense to draw an image" - Warning after upgrade to MountainLion

Tags: warnings, osx-mountain-lion

After I upgraded my programming machine to MountainLion and XCode to the new version I get this warning printed into the console everytime I run my application:

> It does not make sense to draw an image when [NSGraphicsContext
>   currentContext] is nil.  This is a programming error. Break on void
>   _NSWarnForDrawingImageWithNoCurrentContext() to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.

I'm not using an Image anywhere in my Application and I searched the whole project for an image but couldn't find one. Does anybody know what could cause this?

I'm using 2 nib files btw: One Popover and the Mainwindow. Neither of them contains an image.

Edit:
I found the line when this appears:

```
    [self.popover showRelativeToRect:[appDelegate.menulet frame] 
                              ofView:appDelegate.menulet 
                       preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
```

But none of those object is nil. Any suggestions?

Edit 2:
The Menulet is a NSView subclass btw. So I'm passing a view.

Comment: Did you set the breakpoint where it said to?  Post the stack trace when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: How can I find out were to put it? It doesn't show me the yellow warning sign, I just get this message. There is a date and my applicationname followed by "[6686:303]". I checked every class in line 303, but couldn't find a thing.

Comment: Read [About the Breakpoint Navigator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/about_breakpoint_navigator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010433-CH6-SW1) and [Adding a Symbolic Breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html).  Put `_NSWarnForDrawingImageWithNoCurrentContext` in the Symbol field and leave the Module field blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the warning resulted in rewriting my menuIcon with a rectangle (Working on a menuBar application). Haven't solved the problem yet, but I know where it came from in my case. If you have a menubar application, check the code which generates your icon.

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting the breakpoint but it is called when the nib loads. So it is very non-specific. I created a copy of the nib and then deleted objects from it one by one until the warning went away. In my case, it was an NSOutlineView. But as as soon as I added a new NSOutlineView, the error came back.

I was finally able to remove the warning by rebuilding the entire NIB by hand. Painstaking but it got rid of the warning.

Comment: Actually recreating the NIB-File fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a NSImageView that's initialized in the nib but with no image set (and you draw the image yourself in code) just set it and the warning will be gone.

Comment: But I had an NSImageView that's initialized in the nib but with no image set. Removing it did removed the error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's because the image size is {0,0}, which "doesn't make sense".
Actually, the image is for a NSButton, I change the button's image programmatically. In one case, the button should be empty, so I just set an empty image with `[NSImage new]`.
But the error occurs, then no matter how I change the button's image, the button is always empty.
After setting a size to the empty image, the problem is solved, and I can change the button's image successfully.