# Warning when starting Mac Application with imagewell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Since I upgrade my Xcode I get the following warning, when starting my programmed Application:

> 2013-07-03 18:19:03.913 RMC Cone[1414:303] It does not make sense to draw an image when [NSGraphicsContext currentContext] is nil.  This is a programming error. Break on void _NSWarnForDrawingImageWithNoCurrentContext() to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.

But the NSImageView has a image set. So I don't think, that that problem comes from the NSImageView.

Is there a way to find out, which element causes this problem ?

Comment: I've seen thus in console from Apple apps. I suspect it's something in the frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the question: Break on void _NSWarnForDrawingImageWithNoCurrentContext() to debug.

Check rob mayoff's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805741/does-not-make-sense-to-draw-an-image-warning-after-upgrade-to-mountainlion) to find out how to do that.

Comment: thanks, I found out the problem, it was an Button, which has no image ...

Answer (score 0):

The message tells you how to debug the problem:

```
Break on void _NSWarnForDrawingImageWithNoCurrentContext() to debug.
```